# Unresolved reference in build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

Given build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    application
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.21"
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}


ext {
    val projectShortName = "My Project short name"
}

application {
    applicationName = project.ext.get("$projectShortName").toString()
}
```

But when use

```
./gradlew run
```

rise error:

```
* What went wrong:
Script compilation error:

      applicationName = project.ext.get("$projectShortName").toString()
                                                   ^ Unresolved reference: projectShortName

1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra property name here is `projectShortName`. It needs to be accessed like a String, instead of as a variable. So the `$` sign before `projectShortName` in the `project.ext.get()` call needs to be removed. Also the declaration of the property needs to be done differently. There are multiple ways to do it. One of the ways is below:

```kotlin
extra.apply {
    set("projectShortName", "My Project short name")
}

application {
    applicationName = project.ext.get("projectShortName").toString()
}
```